# "Class not found, using default NSManagedObject" with special character in AppName

Tags: ios, core-data

When I use the "-" Character in the App-Name, I get the following Error:

`CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named "<AppName>.<ClassName>" for entity <ClasName>.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.`

I am using CoreData with subclassed NSManagedObjects, so I named all Entity-Class-Names in the DB-File to AppName.ClassName.

Is this character forbidden in App-Names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this applies to NSManagedObjects, but the Apple book "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective C" (under the "Mix and Match" heading, states:

> **Naming Your Product Module**
>
> The name of the Xcode-generated header for Swift code, and the name of the Objective-C bridging header that Xcode creates for you, are generated from your product module name. By default, your product module name is the same as your product name. However, if your product name has any non-alphanumeric characters, such as a period (.), they are replaced with an underscore (_) in your product module name. If the name begins with a number, the first number is replaced with an underscore.”
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.” Apple Inc., 2014-07-31T07:00:00Z. iBooks. 
>   This material may be protected by copyright.
>
> Check out this book on the iBooks Store: https://itun.es/gb/1u3-0.l

This is obviously intended for bridging headers, but I just wonder whether similar rules apply for the CoreData class names.